# Techniques for data thresholding

Tags: machine-learning, threshold

I had a query regarding one of the problems I am trying to solve. I have a few things in mind and would love if you could suggest and/ or point me in the right direction.

Problem Statement - I have a set of data (The data is login times of the users. The time it takes for the users to login into their remote desktop. We just have the numbers and no idea of which is good or bad). I would want to come up with a threshold, saying anything beyond this point is not such a great login experience.

Solution in mind - 1. Detect and remove outliers and then average out (or median) the value to get the threshold. 2. If we can cluster them and do a weighted averaging.

What other approaches do you suggest? Is there a standard technique(s) followed for such kind of problems?

Appreciate your help.

I have posted on stackoverflow, however this channel seemed more appropriate since I am still trying to understand what techniques would suit better. 
Anyway, let me know otherwise.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What is the context? What do you mean by `not such a great login experience`? How do you define that?

Comment: I want to understand if just based on this data can  we get a threshold value.

Comment: I want to come up with a baseline using all the historical data. And want to know if that is even possible and if yes what kind of techniques are generally available.

Comment: We're gonna need more context and some explanation. What would this baseline be?